How to resolve Roslyn CA1827 when using named constant
The following code is a simplified example of a class we're seeing roslyn error CA1827.
public class Test
{
    public const int NumberOfItemsToTriggerBehaviour = 1;

    public static void DoSomething(IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        if (items.Count() < NumberOfItemsToTriggerBehaviour) //CA1827 is triggered here
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}

I'm guessing that roslyn is effectively treating the conditional statement as if (items.Count() < 1) in which case I understand that Any() would be preferable.
However, the goal with this code is to allow us to change the behaviour simply by updating the constant's value. We don't want to have to change the logic in the conditional statement if we change the minimum to... say 2 or greater.
I've considered the following solutions:
if (items.ToList().Count < NumberOfItemsToTriggerBehaviour) - This feels like unnecessary processing
public static readonly int NumberOfItemsToTriggerBehaviour = 1; - This loses the ability to have the value set at compile time
Is there another option I've not considered? Or should I raise this as an issue on the roslyn-analyzers github repo?
Any suggestions welcomed.

Can you just suppress it?  #pragma warning disable CA1827

I would use ICollection rather than IEnumerable.  It’s generally bad practice to Count() arbitrary IEnumerable, which is the point of the warning.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes, that would be a very good way of avoiding that and making the semantics clearer

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft Oh wow, I hadn't considered ICollection. I knew Count() isn't ideal, but hadn't considered setting it to an ICollection to make use of the Count property. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as such. :)

A key part of the CA1827 description is "These methods enumerate the entire collection to compute the count."  That's a performance problem on large IEnumerable<T>'s, if the system isn't able to take an internal shortcut (e.g. casting to a collection class).  @David gives a good solution, using a more specific type (another option is IList<T>, depending what it's used for), where that type is understood to have an efficient Count property.

Ultimately, I have to agree with the compiler here in the general case - because if items is a non-trivial sequence (i.e. the IList etc short-cuts can't be used), then .Count() is going to need to do a considerable amount of work (a lot of .MoveNext() on an enumerator), where-as .Any() is much more efficient (only needing to do one call to .MoveNext()).
So, if you're happy to ignore that aspect: that's when #pragma and [SuppressMessage(...)] come into play; the IDE will help you emit these in the right places. And if the constant changes such that this is no longer needed, it'll become IDE0079 instead (remove unnecessary suppression), so you can re-evaluate as the constant changes.

Right, I know that the best practice is to use the "least-specialized type possible" and to "avoid using ICollection or ICollection as a parameter just to access the Count property" (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/…), but indeed, this seems like a good case of a more specialised type being necessary in order to avoid a lot of calls to MoveNext(). I'm satisfied with this as the answer, in addition to the comments left on the original post.

I think passing IEnumerable is a general exception to this rule.  Because an IEnumerable may not even be able to be enumerated twice, about the only safe thing to do with an IEnumerable is copy it to a list.  And passing an ICollection or IList is obviously better than always making a copy of the collection.
